# Getting Error while creating Sales Order through code

Tags: acumatica

I am Creating sales order from Opportunity through framework code in my custom plugin and ti uses transfer type with custom fields. This code is working fine in 22 R2, When I upgrade to 23 R2, I am not facing error while compiling, but throw the following error.

```
A data corruption state has been detected. You cannot save the changes. Copy the data you have entered and reload the page. Date and Time: 2023-11-03T12:44:11; IncidentID: 62bc4a55-2309-4a27-a519-9c99da35f9bb; Name: Aggregate Validation: PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder+openSiteCntr. You can view detailed information about the issue on the System Events tab of the System Monitor (SM201530) form.
```

While debugging the OpenLineCtrl & Opensitecntl is not setting value and manually assigning the value is not working

Comment: Can you your code that doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Yes.. I have debugged the code and SOOrderSite openlinecntr field is not updating and there is a aggregator validation on OpenShipmentCntr looking into the field and it throws error due to that validatation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because the OpenLine boolean value was not updated; it remained false. Consequently, the openlincnt values were not properly updated in both the soorder DAC and the soordersite DAC.

Comment: Hi, did you get this error on a production site? And how did you resolve it? We have the same error since updating to 23.112.0032 this past weekend. 

I also can't reproduce it on a local instance. In the meantime, I opened a case with Acumatica and await a reply.

Comment: Through my customization code, I've set the 'openline' field value to 'true' for the sales order line when the inventory item is a stock item or when receipt is required for a non-stock item. This action successfully resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Acumatica responded that they cleared out legacy data on our instance that was interfering with the new validation on the SumCalc.